# Solve $x = \sqrt[x]2$

Tags: exponential-function

How does one solve $x = \sqrt[x]2$ for $x$? This can be otherwise stated as

$x = 2^{1/x}$

Raising both sides to the power of $x$:

$x^x = (2^{1/x})^x$
$x^x = 2$

But I don't know where I can go from here.

Comment: You will need to use the Lambert W function : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: There exists a solution $x>0$, it is unique, it is such that $$x\ln x=\ln2,$$ and it cannot be expressed in terms of usual functions. [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) will provide the essentially useless formula $$\ln x=W(\ln2).$$

Comment: Alternately, if this is a homework problem, this may be the time to use your calculator's root-finding methods.

Comment: Purely curiosity – I had already found a numerical solution, but I hoped for an expression. Lambert W function it is; I'll have a look.

Comment: There is no closed form solution for this problem. Even the Lambert W function is not an elemenary function. You could express the solution by using fixed point iteration.